# How to let menu item execute Javascript in Joomla 3.2?

Tags: joomla3.2

Before 3.2, I can set the menu item type to "external link" and then set the link as

"javascript:*myFunction()*"

When clicked, the menu item will call the JavaScript function. But after I upgraded to 3.2, when I did the same thing and tried to save the menu item, it said "Save not permitted".

Did 3.2 block this usage? If yes, how do I get my JS function executed by a menu item?

Answer (score 4):

I've came up this problem a while ago, in Joomla version 3.2.1 concerning a 'Skype' link, e.g.

> skype:myloginname

This has to do with the **protocol types** that are allowed and are defined in this file:

/administrator/components/com_menus/controllers/item.php, line ~180.

There is an array that defines the acceptable schemes:

```
$scheme = array('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'gopher', 'mailto', 'news', 'prospero', 'telnet', 'rlogin', 'tn3270', 'wais', 'url', 'mid', 'cid', 'nntp', 'tel', 'urn', 'ldap', 'file', 'fax', 'modem', 'git');
```

When adding `skype` at the end of the list Joomla! allowed saving the external link. The same applies for `javascript`. In any case you should consider any security risk that comeswith this solution.

In addition, you should take into mind that this override may be discarded in any future update of joomla.

Comment: The same works for Joomla 4, but the file is administrator\components\com_menus\src\Controller\ItemController.php

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking Joomla thinks that `javascript` is a protocol, like HTTP & Co., it looks it up inside a list of known protocols, it does not find it and it throws an error.

Start reading at around line inside `[MenusControllerItem::save()][1]`. So basically it has nothing to do with the fact you are trying to use some JavaScript, **this is just a side-effect.**

While using JavaScript in the External Link is not really an advertised feature but rather said a loophole, it does break b/c if you have used before.

**You can:**

1. **Open an issue** in the [Joomla Issue Tracker](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id=8103) and report this issue, get some community feedback. The fix is really easy, it just needs to get accepted.
2. Use the **suggestion below**:

   - Instead of link put #
   - Set the field "Link CSS Style" to something that does not colide with other classes, eg. `my-function`
   - Save
   - You can use jQuery to intercept the click event on the link and to make it run your function. See code below:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       // Select element based on the class set in Joomla backend
       $( ".my-function" ).on( "click", function(e) {
           // Do not follow the link
           e.preventDefault();

           // Call function
           myFunction(1);
       });
   });


   function myFunction(x)
   {
       alert("I was called" + x);
   }
   ```

**Update**: after a short discussion with the commiter of the change, I understood that it may be related to a security issue. So it may be on purpose after all not to allow js.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually went to learn some jQuery and figured it out before I saw your post. It was joyful when you are forced to learn new things.